# Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'EXECUTE STRING' within a function error message

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql

I have searched for this error online and tried to use dynamic SQL. I am still getting 'Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'EXECUTE STRING' within a function' Please let me know if there are any suggestions. I appreciate any help.

```
  ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_get_type_ids]
    (
        @category_id  int = null, 
        @all_id          int = null,
        @category_id_op varchar(20) = null,
        @all_op  varchar(20) = null,
    )  
    RETURNS @TypeIDs table
    (
        type_id int
    )
    AS
    BEGIN


        IF (@category_id_op = 'Is')
        BEGIN
            SET @category1 = ('level_1_id = @category_id')
        END
        ELSE IF (@category_id_op = 'IS NOT')
        BEGIN
            SET @category1 = ('level_1_id <> @category_id OR level_1_id IS NULL') 
        END    

        IF (@all_op = 'Is')
        BEGIN
            SET @category2 = ('level_2_id = @all_id')
        END
        ELSE IF (@all_op = 'Is NOT')
        BEGIN
            SET @category2 = ('level_2_id <> @all_id OR level_1_id IS NULL') 
        END    


            DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)

           set @sql = 'insert into @TypeIDs 
                     SELECT atr.type_id
              FROM type_rel atr 
                      LEFT JOIN category_ref acr1 ON atr.level_1_id = acr1.category_id
                      WHERE (' + @category1 + ' AND ' +  @category2 + ')' 


    exec (@sql)

     RETURN 
    END
```

Comment: You cannot use Dynamic sql inside a SQL Server user define function... Use Stored Procedure for this....

Comment: You don't actually need dynamic sql here. You could do `WHERE (@category_id_op = 'Is' AND level_1_id = @category_id)  OR (@category_id_op = 'IS NOT' and level_1_id <> @category_id OR level_1_id IS NULL)....`

Comment: In addition to the suggestions above, I'd add declare all variables (@category1 and @category2) and use sp_executesql instead of exec (@sql).